# BindingList<T> datasource for DataGridView

Tags: .net, datagridview, bindinglist

I have a BindingList that I would like to use for a datasource on a DataGrid view.
I added dataGridView1 and button 1 to a form.
When I press the button, nothing shows up on the dataGridView.  If I use a DataTable for the data source it works fine.  I must be missing something simple.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<ClassificationInfo> boundList;
    ClassificationInfo item;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        boundList = new BindingList<ClassificationInfo>();

        item = new ClassificationInfo();
        item.bExclude = 1;
        item.iColor = 123456;
        item.szDescription = "Test line 1";
        boundList.Add(item);    

        item = new ClassificationInfo();
        item.bExclude = 0;
        item.iColor = 7890123;
        item.szDescription = "Test line 2";
        item.iOrder = 2;
        boundList.Add(item);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = boundList;
    }    

    public class ClassificationInfo
    {
        public int iColor;
        public int iOrder;
        public string szDescription;
        public int bExclude;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn your public fields on ClassificationInfo into properties.

```
public class ClassificationInfo 
{ 
    public int iColor { get; set; }
    public int iOrder { get; set; }
    public string szDescription { get; set; }
    public int bExclude { get; set; }
}
```

DataBinding in just about every case relies on a [TypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171819.aspx), which uses PropertyDescriptors to discover properties. Fields are ignored (as they should be - they should be encapsulated), so your data binding doesn't work.

Comment: This worked.  Thanks.  How did you format my post correctly?  I thought I posted it between code tags, but the entire block of code wasn't highlighted when it posted.

Comment: This site doesn't use code tags, not sure where you got that. While you're editing a post, there's a summary on the right of what you can do, or you just click the code button (1s and 0s) in the editor with the code selected (code formatting is 4 spaces at the beginning of the line).